# Google App Engine large IN clause query

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

I have an Account entity that has a facebook id.

Sometimes, the client might send all facebook ids (the clients facebook friends) to the server.

We want to select all Accounts IN the facebook ids the client provided.

Looping and calling get on each facebook id seems rather slow, considering people might have 1000+  friends. Further more, GAE is limited to 30 queries with IN clause.

Has anyone had a similar situation? How did you handle it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a model that uses the facebook ID as a key which allows you to use Model. get_by_key_name(key_names=fb_ids) to fetch all the models with keys in fb_ids at once.

e.g.

```
class FBModel(db.Model):
   account = db.ReferenceProperty(reference_class=Account)
```

When creating the model:

```
model = FBModel(key_name=fb_id)
```

Comment: Does this imply the user has to upload all his facebook friends to the server beforehand or simply update my account entity with his facebook_id?

Comment: Are you trying to get the friends data from facebook's api or your database? obviously your friends friends will have to have an account with you for you to have their facebook ID and information.

Comment: Each client will receive and store the facebook friends into their own  device (its a mobile app). Then when I execute the GAE request, I take this whole database and serialize it into a JSONArray and send it over.

Then the server will take this data and try to find all accounts within the set the client supplied.

I think your solution might do it, I saw a video about something similar.

if you have more info, please comment, I am interested :) Otherwise, I will try that out and mark the response.